QoS during non-congestion
I am currently studying QoS and I have a question regarding queuing during non-congestion times.  I would just like to confirm whether my understanding is correct regarding queuing during non-congestion.
I originally thought that QoS only does its job during congestion. I thought that packets would never end up or wait in a queue if the link isn't congested.
Then I've read that it's actually a common misconception is to think that QoS doesn't have any effect if there is no congestion. Even if we have a link that isn't congested, if two or more packets come into the device at the same time, the device can only put one on the wire and temporarily queue the other ones, correct?
So even without congestion, queuing can and will still occur.
So something like this, despite the link not being fully utilized, can still introduce latency to applications such as VOIP, correct?
However, isn't such queuing extremely fast if there is no congestion?
If two or more packets arrive at the same time, wouldn't it be a matter of maybe even microseconds before they are sent out? Or can this really introduce a delay high enough that it would have a visible impact on VOIP applications?
Thank you for your time.

If there is no congestion, then a packet can immediately be sent out the interface. There is no QoS software queuing.

if two or more packets come into the device at the same time, the
device can only put one on the wire and temporarily queue the other
ones, correct?

The definition of congestion is more traffic than the interface can handle at any time. In fact an interface has a FIFO hardware queue, albeit small. Think about the fact that one of those two packets will actually be received and routed to the next interface first, which will use the hardware FIFO queue.
If the frame uses 1538 bytes including overhead (12,304 bits) of bandwidth on a 1 Gbps ethernet interface interface, it will only take 0.000012304 seconds to send it, and the hardware queue will not have been filled by then, so there is no reason to put it into the QoS software queues.
Basically, the two packets can move straight from the routing process (table lookup, frame generation, etc.) to the interface hardware queue, bypassing the QoS configured software queues.
If the interface can send faster than the FIFO hardware queue being filled, there is no congestion, and no need to slow things with the QoS software queues.
